# WebView not loading images nor css on some Android devices

Tags: android, css, webview

I load html files on webview along with css applied using the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     testWV = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview1);

     testWV.setDelegate(this);
     testWV.setApplicationLanguage(((iKitabApp) getApplication()).getLanguage());

     testWV.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
     testWV.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
     testWV.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
     testWV.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
     testWV.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
         testWV.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
        );
     }
     testWV.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}


new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             testWV.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    
                    testWV.loadDataWithBaseURL(filePath,  htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", "about:blank");
                }
            });
        }
});
```

Recently on some android devices as Galaxy 6 and note 10, the WebView is no longer loading the images in the WebView nor applying the css file which comes with it. While it's still loading the whole content correctly on other android devices.

Kindly find below the result of the same html file on 2 different android devices

[image]
[image]

Would you kindly advise on the matter.

Comment: sorry, i didnt notice i sent a reply instead of a comment, is there any useful output in the debug console ?

Comment: unfortunately I was not able to reproduce the issue on an android device on my side, but it's showing with customers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following setting and finally it worked:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```